# How do I model this image? I’m new to blender

Tags: modeling, mesh

[image]
Hi I’m new to blender and for days I’ve been trying to wrap my head around this. I’ve tried using the torus and besier curve but my model doesn’t come out as geometric as the picture particularly the metal attachment connecting to the nuts[image]

Comment: Hi. Please make the title of your question specific to the problem you are having and not just the general topic. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a two toruses and a path with thickness, nothing really to advice about. Use the picture as reference and copy the curve as it goes, then add two circle parts.

I created two circles, then one of the nut holder. Changed the origin point so it mirror right. Apply another mirror modifier and chose the the circle as mirror object. Moved the vertexes of the holders up. If you scaling or so, dont forget to CTRL+A to apply scale and rotation, so it will work ok. Then just add depth in geometry.

[image: stepbystep]

Comment: Keep in mind, OP is completely new to blender. A few more details/screenshots would be great.

Comment: @Ochaya Designs ,if any of it seems to be hard or isn't clear feel free to ask :-)

Comment: @Fowl this is golden information! You have no idea how much this helps! I had already spent about two weeks trying to wrap my head around that concept you’ve shared. Clear as day! Thank you